# From T-Sql to Linq-to-SQL

Tags: sql-server, linq, t-sql, lambda

I need a very simple query in my aplication but I can't figure out how to translate it into Linq-to-SQL because I need it in an asp.net application.

It is neccesery that it is a lambda expression because of internal procedures.

In T-SQL it looks like this:

```
select top 1 [datum] 
from Test 
where Datum <> (select max (Datum) from Test)
```

Sorry for the stupid question in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Max` function inline with the query

```
var result = Test
    .Where(t => t.Datum != Test.Max(t1 => t1.Datum))
    .Select(t => t.Datum)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You can move the expression from the `.Where()` to the `.FirstOrDefault()` and remove the `.Where()`

Comment: Yes, but that's just syntactic sugar and personal preference, it has no affect on the query itself

Answer (score 0):

To apply such query using lambda expression first you need to fetch all records from table test and the list that you get can be used to get the output you want.
Sample query would be as follows after you fetch the list from the database.

var test= Tests
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.datum)
    .Skip(1)
    .First();